# Stripe Secret and Publishable key validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, stripe-payments

Is there any validation like length of key or any else for secret key and publishable key in Stripe account.

I want in Php, jQuery, javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripe: Validating Publishable and Secret API Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388204/stripe-validating-publishable-and-secret-api-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Stripe secret API keys start with either `sk_live_` (for live keys) or `sk_test_` (for test keys).

Similarly, Stripe publishable API keys start with `pk_live_` or `pk_test_`.

Comment: There are a number of old api keys (still around), that don't follow this convention